# Word VBA macro working on some computers but not other

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've written a pretty simple Word macro to hide different parts of a form based on a checkbox made at the beginning of the form. It's only working on some people's computers but not others - it's uploaded to our document server and then users download it out.

Specifically, affected users are able to click a checkbox and the macro will disable the other checkboxes, but the bookmarks remain visible. No error shows up, it just doesn't happen.

The file is downloaded correctly (.docm) and when I poke around in affected users' VBA code, nothing seems to be amiss. I haven't been able to replicate the error myself.

Below is the macro. Any help would be appreciated, as this supports a fairly important business process.

```
'Plan
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    CheckBox4.Enabled = False
    CheckBox5.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    CheckBox4.Enabled = True
    CheckBox5.Enabled = True
End If
Bookmarks("CAPA_Plan_And_Add").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
'Plan Addendum
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox1.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    CheckBox4.Enabled = False
    CheckBox5.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    CheckBox4.Enabled = True
    CheckBox5.Enabled = True
End If
Bookmarks("CAPA_Plan_And_Add").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox2.Value
End Sub
'Execution
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox4.Enabled = False
    CheckBox5.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    CheckBox4.Enabled = True
    CheckBox5.Enabled = True
End If
Bookmarks("CAPA_Execution").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox3.Value
End Sub
'Extension
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
If CheckBox3.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    CheckBox5.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    CheckBox5.Enabled = True
End If
Bookmarks("CAPA_Extension").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox4.Value
Bookmarks("CAPA_Extension_2").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox4.Value
End Sub
'Cancellation
Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()
If CheckBox4.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    CheckBox4.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    CheckBox4.Enabled = True
End If
Bookmarks("CAPA_Cancellation").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox5.Value
Bookmarks("CAPA_Cancellation_2").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox5.Value
End Sub
'Effectiveness Check Yes
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
If CheckBox7.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox7.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox7.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
'Effectiveness Check No
Private Sub CheckBox7_Click()
If CheckBox6.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox6.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox6.Enabled = True
End If
Bookmarks("Effectiveness_Check").Range.Font.Hidden = CheckBox7.Value
End Sub


Private Sub CheckBox9_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Do the book marks definitely exists?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What specifically is not working? To help prompt more info please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68924547/edit) the question and explain what "not working" means.

Comment: If the hidden text remains visible have you checked File | Options | Display? It has a setting to always show hidden text. If this is checked the hidden text will remain visible but will have a dotted underline.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with this code logical & syntax wise.

**Logical**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
```

It doesn't make any sense to me why you are basing what checkboxes are `Enabled` based on a different checkbox than the one which was clicked; specifically without regard to the state of the checkbox that was clicked.  This looks like an ugly work around for not understanding how to initialize and properly control event clicks.

**Syntactically**

An If Statement looks like this:

```
If condition Then
' Do something if true
End If
```

An If-Else statement is formatted like this:

```
If condition Then
' Do something if true
Else
' Do something else
End if
```

Labels, used in {On Error} Goto Label statements are formatted with a colon after a name

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
' Some code that might produce an error

ErrorHandler:
' More code (to deal with errors)
```

So what you have is a normal If-Statement (without an Else component, since it has a colon after it `Else:`) which should enable all checkboxes.

```
If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox3.Enabled = False
    CheckBox4.Enabled = False
    CheckBox5.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    CheckBox3.Enabled = True
    CheckBox4.Enabled = True
    CheckBox5.Enabled = True
End If
```

**[TL;DR]**
Just remove the colon after the `Else` statements

Comment: Thank you for outlining this so thoroughly! This is my first macro. Unfortunately, this change didn't resolve the issue - I still have some users who can use the macros and some for whom the hidden bookmarks don't work.